# return of parameters from matlab script

Tags: matlab

let us suppose that we have following function

```
function [y1,y2,y3,y4]=mystery(a,x);
y1=a*x;
y2=a*x^2;
y3=a^2*x^2;

y4=a*x^3+5;
end
```

now what i want to make sure is order of result returned from this code,for instance

```
[y1,y2,y3,y4]=mystery(3,5);
```

does it return in reverse order or  directly  in direct  form?i meant when m file is executed does it first return last result,then previous of last line and so on?thanks in advance

Comment: yes of course,sometimes  it may matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters are always returned in the order of the declaration. The order of evalutation does not matter. So, in your case, you will always have the order `[y1,y2,y3,y4]`.

Edit:
If you want to access the second or third parameter only, you can do `[~,y2]=mystery(1,2)` or `[~,~,y2]=mystery(1,2)` respectively.

Comment: if i write  [a]=mystery(3,5)  it will return y1?

Comment: @datodatuashvili Why not try it yourself and see? Try to explore.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab executes line by line in the script. The first line is always executed first.

Comment: yes but when i  write [y1]=mystery(3,5) first line would be  returned?

Comment: @datodatuashvili Not first line, just the value of `y1`.

Comment: The first line of the function is the function signature. It is seen at first for inputs and at the very end for outputs.